# Microsoft Graph API odata $filter query does not appear to work

Tags: api, filter, microsoft-graph-api, odata

I am trying to filter a set of data returned by the MS Graph API's [managedDevices endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/intune-devices-manageddevice-list?view=graph-rest-1.0) using an odata filter.

Sending the request without a filter gets the expected result.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/managedDevices
```

returns this response:

```json
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#deviceManagement/managedDevices",
    "@odata.count": 5,
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "kj23kj4-0d47-34f3-8ff0-6b5sdfsdf3332f",
            "userId": "asdfasw-1b48-436d-aa42-3werwer2344",
            "deviceName": "some_device_name_9/16/2020_6:31 PM"
            ...
```

When I send ***any*** of the following requests I get the exact same response with 5 results:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/deviceManagement/managedDevices?$filter=id eq 'kj23kj4-0d47-34f3-8ff0-6b5sdfsdf3332f'
```

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/deviceManagement/managedDevices?$filter=id in ('lksjdf...','qwerqwer...')
```

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/deviceManagement/managedDevices?$filter=ownerType ne 'personal'
```

I didn't see this listed on [uservoice](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests?category_id=359584) as an issue others are having specifically. They also apparently don't explicitly call out what odata query params are and aren't supported for specific endpoints. $select, for example, does work on this endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this problem, I test it in my side also can't do the filter. And the odata url is correct, so I think the field `id` just not be designed to do filter.

If you want to do filter with `id`, you can use `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/deviceManagement/managedDevices/{id}` directly. It can get the result with specific "id", maybe it is why the field `id` not be designed to do filter.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up submitting a post on uservoice to see if this can be added. The Graph API seems very inconsistent so far. I ended up using batch requests to the endpoint you mentioned. I also just found out that some actions like remoteLock at ```https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/deviceManagement/managedDevices/{id}/remoteLock``` do not work in the batch format for some reason. MS is giving me headaches this week.